# Where does authenticate method find users and password?

Tags: django

I have a login form. I need to authenticate users. All information about usernames and their passwords are stored in PostgreSQL database. I find such method:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
```

How does Django know whether such user exists or no? How to combine it with DB? Is it necessary to create models or just to read data from database?

Comment: You should really really read [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/) for this.

Comment: Is it necessary to create users? What if I have a huge database, that contains users? I have to represent those DB users in user models?

Comment: I don't understand your distinction between "data from database" and "users". Users are represented as models in the database.

Comment: Ok. Look, I gonna try to explain. I have a huge DB. There is a table USERS. It has 10 columns, some of them are USERNAME and PASSWORD. I have a login form, and I want to check if there is such user in DB.

Comment: I have to create new model classes for each table? Or somehow import database and models will be created automatically?

Comment: Why not use [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/) to generate the models for you? But I do hope you're not storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: django does not store the passwords in plain text so you can't just slot in your pre-existing database of usernames and plaintext passwords and use django as a front end for auth.

Comment: It stores passwords with MD5.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, one stupid question: When I generate models with inspectdb, how can I fill these models with data from DB?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the concept of a "model" in a Django context. What you do mean by "how can I fill these models with with data from DB"?

Comment: When I create a model, it acts like CREATE TABLE in SQL. But to fill models with data, I must do something like this: p = Person(name="Fred Flintstone", shirt_size="L") p.save(). So, when I use inspectdb, it will initialize all models with data or just create models?